# Disconnect an observer in JS

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I created this function through some online guides, basically it is an `observer`, it works perfectly but once activated it always remains in "observation". I've read the documentation and i found a function: `disonnect()` but does not work, does anyone have any ideas on how to stop the observer working at the job finish?

I have try to set `obs.disconnect()` after `obs.observe(obj, { childList: true, subtree: true });`;

```
const getFavTable = () => {
  const observeDOM = (
    (
      () => {
        const MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver;
        const eventListenerSupported = window.addEventListener;

        return (obj, callback) => {
          if (MutationObserver) {
            // define a new observer
            const obs = new MutationObserver((mutations, observer) => {
              if (mutations[0].addedNodes.length || mutations[0].removedNodes.length) {
                callback();
              }
            });

            // have the observer observe foo for changes in children
            obs.observe(obj, { childList: true, subtree: true });
          } else if (eventListenerSupported) {
            obj.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', callback, false);
            obj.addEventListener('DOMNodeRemoved', callback, false);
          }
        };
      }
    )
)();

// Observe a specific DOM element:
observeDOM(document.querySelector('body'), () => {
  console.log('dom changed');

  if (document.querySelector('#todayfavtable') != null) {
    document.querySelector('#todayfavtable').scrollIntoView();
  } else {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }
});
```

Comment: "but does not work" What specifically did you try? Where do you want to trigger this disconnect in the logic you've listed?

Comment: i have updated my question.

Comment: That would disconnect it right away, thus observing nothing? What is the goal of stopping observation in this case? Would you for instance want to put it next to `callback()`?

Comment: i need to stop it after document.querySelector('#todayfavtable').scrollIntoView();